# How can I cause SVG elements to render in high DPI in Safari on a Retina MacBook?

Tags: svg, safari, retina-display

[This website](http://couplespsychology.com) uses all vector graphics (SVG). In Safari on a MacBook Pro with Retina display some elements render in hi-DPI mode and yet some in low-resolution (and then pixel doubles).

They are all rendered in high-definition in Chrome.

What determines whether an SVG element is rendered in high DPI or low DPI in Safari on OS X? Is it possible to force Safari to render an element in high DPI on a retina screen?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question is entirely on-topic -- SVG is as much a web technology as HTML and this question is relevant to developers.